# Issues on to calculate difference between previous quarter and current quarter

Tags: dax

I am with the issue of difference between previous quarter, next quarter and current quarter. I have created date field and use the following calculation to resolve the issue but there is showing aggregated 4 quarters total instead of difference between last quarter and current quarter. The attached screenshot showing the grand total figure and quarter difference figure is same.

But the result is same. Only showing the total figure to sum all quarters. Please help me to find out the way to resolve the issue.

```
=IF (
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( 
            '10QuarterlyReportProgressPC'[Quarter], 1 ) = "Q1",
             SUM ('10QuarterlyReportProgressPC'[Progress] ),
             SUM( '10QuarterlyReportProgressPC'[Progress] )
             - CALCULATE ( SUM ( '10QuarterlyReportProgressPC'[Progress] 
             ), 
             PREVIOUSQUARTER ( '10QuarterlyReportProgressPC'[Start_QuarterYear] ) )
```

)

Comment: I have tried another way:

=var _thisQ = TOTALQTD(
[Sum of Progress], '10QuarterlyReportProgressPC'[Start_QuarterYear] )

var _lastQ = TOTALQTD(
[Sum of Progress] , PREVIOUSQUARTER( '10QuarterlyReportProgressPC'[Start_QuarterYear]),

VALUES('10QuarterlyReportProgressPC'[Quarter]) )

RETURN
IF(_lastQ = 0,
BLANK(),
_thisQ - _lastQ
)

 

But the result is same. Only showing the total figure to sum all quarters.

Comment: If you have a date table in your data model, you can use DAX time intelligence functions - in this case, `PARALLELPERIOD` would make your quarter on quarter comparison easy.